# My Hat Dash record scores don't show only until I play one round - winter bash

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I sometimes play Hat Dash, but I also want to see my record scores. But I realize that when you click the Hat Dash button, your top scores do not show, it's is just a big blank space below the unicorn...

Here is the image:

[image]

And I also realized it only shows after you play one round, here is an image below after I played one round (I didn't jump):

[image]

As you can see, now my leaderboard for best Hat Dash scores shows after one round.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. If you want to see your top scores without playing the game, go to the bottom of the hat dash leaderboard.

> how well do you jump?
> play one game to see results
> or go leaderboard